# Looking solutions for performing full text search with low memory cost

Tags: mysql, django, full-text-search, django-haystack, whoosh

I wrote a web application using Django to display products information.

My database (MySQL) contains ~200000 records ( fields: brand, name, and img). I want to add a search function to my app (the search is performed on brand and name fields).

I tried haystack with Whoosh, but I found it cost a lot of memory.

Can anyone suggest a way to do it? The application is expected running on a cheap AWS EC2 (small memory).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have figure out a solution. My current approach is using Xapian as haystack's backend. I picked this solution because it is easy to be integrated into a Django project. The memory consumption is very small (less than 100mb in my case), and it is also fast.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Memory vs speed is ultimately a trade-off. I would recommend Elasticsearch but the baseline memory requirement for that would be atleast 256 MB (mainly for the JVM). You can perhaps try using [Typesense](https://github.com/typesense/typesense) which has a much lower baseline memory footprint (probably less than 10 MB).

However, remember that speed vs memory is always a trade-off.